# Why do the circles not always appear in this JS animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have this script I want to use, very simple stuff. I can't pinpoint the issue though, the circles should appear continuously, endlessly but if you keep watching it, some circles just don't show. They are being created but just don't show up front end. Any ideas?

```js
counter = 0;
  
function createCircle(){
  
  $("body").append("<div class='circle'></div>");
    
  // add "zoom" class
  setTimeout(function(){
      $(".circle:last-child").addClass("zoom");
  },10);
  
  // Remove circle
  setTimeout(function(){
      $(".circle:first").remove();
  },3000);
  counter++;
}

setInterval(function(){
    createCircle();
},500);
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.circle.zoom {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've noticed that the circles start to disappear when they're not visible in the viewport...

Comment: if you watch it for a minute, some stop showing up completely.

Comment: Why not create a looping CSS animation instead? Rather than manipulating the DOM...

Comment: I could... but I just want to know what is the issue with this particular approach :)

Comment: It's probably due to conflicting timeouts? Also, rather than referencing `$(".circle')` all the time, stick it in a variable before you insert into the body, and then use the variable for the class name adjustment, and dom removal.